# How to ordain and become a monk?

Tags: vipassana, meditation-insight, monk, meditation-recommendation, ordination

I want to devote my life to Buddhist way of meditation, I want to know more of Buddha teaching but my main interest is for go day and night actual meditation practices. I accidentally come across Sri S. N. Goyenka Vipassana retreats and attended one 10 day retreat at Dhamma Sota-New Delhi, after that from one year i'm practicing Vipassana meditation 2-4 hours daily at home. Now i'm very clear i want to devote my life for this.Its be very helpful if anyone can guide me into this.

Comment: Best of luck!!!

Comment: Hi! I took the liberty to edit the title to formulate it as a question.

Comment: I think i'm not very good in actually asking a good question, there may be something left which needed to be answered so feel free to edit so that it can help me or anyone seeking this type of information as there is no information available on this topic.

Comment: One piece of advise would be for you to visit a select few monasteries in one or more traditions and spend a month or two at each place meditating and mixing with the monks. Pick the one you feel comfortable with, and ask the abbot there on the process for ordaining. It is often a common desire that comes about when in meditation to ordain, however it is wise to not be in a hurry, but to observe that emotion, and deconstruct it just like one examines any problematic emotion in life. May you succeed.

Comment: Hope this book will give you an understanding of the procedure inside, but I think above comment is the answer to the question you asked. http://www.buddhanet.net/pdf_file/ordination.pdf . However my hope is, may you succeed!

Answer (score 6):

Hope this video, "[Ask A Monk: How To Ordain As A Monk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ittQd5zk0ok)" by Yuttadhammo Bhikkhu would help you! And hope you will achieve what you want!

Comment: already gone through this. Its did't give much details of how actually you become and more deep things.

Comment: I think the best thing is going to a monastery and discuss with the priests about your intention. I am not sure whether there are regional variations, however in Sri Lanka, some Monasteries have low acceptance rates and you will have to spend some months in the monastery getting used to the environment before getting ordained. Here is how a German became ordained in Sri Lanka(http://www.sundaytimes.lk/140105/news/from-mayor-in-germany-to-monk-in-mihintale-78876.html), but it is not detailed enough. I think the best thing is meeting a priest from a monastery you like.

Comment: Hi. It would be nice if you could [summarize or extend your answer with the most important parts of the video](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Find a place where they can welcome you, stay a few months, practice. Ordaining is not for lifetime for Buddhists, and you may change your mind after a few days/weeks/months/years, that's quite unpredictable, even though you may feel now you will stay a monk forever. No need to know that in advance.

I can recommend the temple in Chom Tong, they have an international section (you don't have to speak Thai to train there) and do hardcore practice, which sounds like something you want. You can stay there both as a lay person or ordain if you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @eudoxos. Can you please give more details about temple in chom tong temple any link website etc? Yes you are right, this may be just a initial attraction and one more thing got in my mind that you can stay in busy city, work, do all things normal people do and follow most of the eight fold path. you don't need to wear a robe and be in jungle for that.

Comment: There are e-mails to Thanat Chindaporn (head of the international section) in http://www.northernvipassana.org/about.html . Or call them, there is a phone number at http://www.dhammathai.org/e/meditation/page28.php (which otherwise contains also outdated information). For the start go for the basic/foundational course (3 weeks) and possibly stay longer for retreats. You will see where it takes you. They are quite big and flexible and if you practice, they let you stay there. It is the same temple where @yuttadhammo trained AFAIK. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The links on this page may be useful (since it is a Vipassana Tradition in Sri Lanka): [Nā Uyana Aranya -- Theeravada Buddhist Forest Monastery](http://nauyana.org/)

[Information for visitors](http://nauyana.org/files/Na_Uyana_Monastery_Information.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

These are two prominent places in Sri Lanka. Sri Lanka offers 1 year residence visa easily if you have a recommendation from a monastery.

1. **Mitirigala Nissarana Vanaya**

   - Teacher- Ven. Udairiyagama Dhammajiva Maha Thero (U Dhammajiva
     Sayadaw), Excellent knowledge in Dhamma, Pali, Burmese and English, Specialty in Mindfulness and emphasizes the value of mindfulness
   - Meditation Technique - Satipatthana meditation, Burmese Mahasi/Panditarama Technique (Vipassana) and [Sri
     Lankan Nanarama Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nissarana_Vanaya_Meditation_System) (Vipassana with Samatha)
   - Retreats - 3 days, 7 days, 10 days, 20 days and extensive periods are
     allowed for serious practitioners and for the meditators who are
     expecting the ordaination
   - Location - Mitirigala,Kirindivela, Sri Lanka
   - More Information - nissarana.lk (Official Website)
2. **Sanghopasthana Suva Sevana**

   - Teacher- Ven. Katukurunde Nyanananda Maha Thero (Bhikkhu Nanananda)
     [A famous book author and a meditation master], Excellent knowledge in Dhamma, Pali and English, Advises not to be in a hurry but to practice Samatha also for aiding Vipassana, Slowly-Mindfully-Carefully. Appreciates dedication for practicing.
   - Meditation Technique - Both Samatha and Vipassana, Metta Meditation
     and probably Sri Lankan Nanarama Method (Vipassana with Samatha)
   - Retreats - Any time is possible with prior notice. No allocated dates. special consideration for dedicated meditators and  dedicated practitioners who are expecting the ordaination.
   - Location - Kirillawala Watta, Dammulla, Karandana, Sri Lanka
   - More Information - http://www.seeingthroughthenet.net (Official
     Website)

Additionally there are more meditation centers which are famous in different aspects. NaUyana Aranya in Melsiripura (Burmese Pa-auk system), Kanduboda M.C. (Burmese Mahasi System), Goenka centers in Kandy, Anuradhapura and Kosgama (Burmese Sayagi U Ba Kin system)